# Assign value from ASP:DataSource query to variable in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datasource

I have an asp:datasource select query that returns a sum.  I want to assign that sum to a variable in the code behind (c#) and then assign that variable to the text of a text box.

How do I assign the result of my select query to a c# variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider setting the data source from the code behind:

```
textbox1.Text = YourDBMethodThatReturnsSum();
```

Comment: I am using <asp:datasource></asp:datasource>  Which also contains my select statement.  Would it be better to write the method in C# instead of ASP?

Comment: @greyhatsalafi - I tend to keep all data access separate from my presentation layer which is what your .aspx pages are, so yes, I think it would be better.